# How to get only enabled products id's in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, core-config-data, product-id

I have created a some fields in Store->Configuration on saving the data connect an observer.

I want to get all enable product id's in that observer file how would i do that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need product select drop down in syste.xml field ?

Comment: No i just want enable product id's @Msquare

Comment: get the product collection and add `$collection->addFieldToFilter('status',1)`